# Why don't we see 'synchronized' as a Data Source tab within Marketing Cloud's Contact Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have installed and subsequently updated the Marketing Cloud Connect to v 5.494.1. We have also updated authentication to the connected app method per the upgrade instructions.

What is puzzling is that data stream doesn't appear to be immediately available. When we enter the **data sources** part of Contact Builder there is no option for synchronized. I am logged in as a API User / Admin user connected to the Sales Cloud connect user on the SFDC side.

Is there something missing from [the documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/integrating_data_into_your_account_with_data_stream/) here? **Does each account wanting to use Data Stream / Synchronized objects need to actually call support for something to be turned on in provisioning?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you would need to reach out to SFMC Support.

They have to enable additional settings on the back-end for this to be fully provisioned.  This is done to ensure all Prerequisites are met as mentioned in the below link.  Hope that helps!

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/connecting_the_clouds/integrating_data_into_your_account_with_data_stream/

Comment: For others: This worked fine. Support got this turned around in no time at all after logging a ticket with Global Support.